# How to query vertex as OrientVertex

Tags: orientdb

I need update vertex and return it as `ODocument`.
First, i query it, then update properties, and finally return it as ODocument.

But I only able to retrieve `Vertex`, not `OrientVertex`:

```
Vertex vPlace = graph.getVertices("id",id).iterator().next();
```

I found example in http://orientdb.com/docs/2.2/Graph-Blueprints.html:

```
Iterable<OrientVertex> results = g.query().has("name", EQUALS, "fast");
```

but it does not compile: "EQUALS" not found.
 How to query vertex as `OrientVertex`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this useful for you?

```java
String dbName = "testDB";

OrientGraphFactory dbfactory = new OrientGraphFactory("remote:127.0.0.1:2424/"+dbName, "root", "root").setupPool(1, 50);

OrientGraph db = dbfactory.getTx();

try {
    String query = "select from V where name = ?";

    Iterable<OrientVertex> result = db.command(new OCommandSQL(query)).execute("testName");

    while(result.iterator().hasNext()){
        OrientVertex d = result.iterator().next();

        //do something with d
        System.out.println(d.getProperty("name"));

    }

} catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            System.out.println(e);
}
```